# r Graphs showing different results

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I've been using sjplot to graph model outputs of binary data which have been going great so far.

However, when I attempt graph the results of the probability of error of each sex, I get different visual results when I use two different scripts using sjplot and ggplot.

For instance, I used the following script to plot the following graph:

```
sexorder <- c( "Female", "Male")

plot_model(model1, type = "pred",show.p=TRUE, terms = "Sex",ci.lvl=0.95,show.data = F,
           axis.title = c("","Probability of Error"),
           title="")+scale_x_discrete(limits=sexorder)
```

[image]

However, when I was playing around try to make my graph more visually appealing, I used the following code to obtain the following graph.

```
library(scales)

ggplot(Mdb, aes(Sex, Erreur)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.2) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=21, fill="red", size=2) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format(), limits=c(0,1))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,0.15))
```

[image]

This brings me to question if I am using the proper method to show my results. Am I using the right method to show the results obtained from my model?

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ggplot` code isn't showing the same thing as `sjPlot`. All your ggplot code does is show the mean value for `Erreur` in the two groups of `Sex`. The `plot_model` function with `type = "pred"` shows you the *marginal effect* of `Sex` on the predictions, that is, the effect `Sex` has on probability if the other variables are held level.

We can demonstrate this with a fictitious data set:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(Sex = rep(rep(c("F", "M"), 2), times = c(900, 900, 100, 100)),
                 ProbErreur = rep(0:1, times = c(1800, 200)),
                 Erreur = rbinom(2000, 1, 
                                 rep(c(0.03, 0.02, 0.9, 0.85), 
                                     times = c(900, 900, 100, 100))))

model1 <- glm(Erreur ~ Sex + ProbErreur, df, family = binomial)
```

This gives us a model where the probability of `Erreur` is very low when `ProbErreur` is 0, but high if `ProbErreur` is 1. There is a small effect of `Sex` too, just as in your own model:

```r
summary(model1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = Erreur ~ Sex + ProbErreur, family = binomial, data = df)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -2.1553  -0.2364  -0.1846  -0.1846   2.8570  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)  -3.5636     0.1890 -18.857   <2e-16 ***
#> SexM         -0.5005     0.2629  -1.904   0.0569 .  
#> ProbErreur    5.7832     0.2733  21.162   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 1365.03  on 1999  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance:  530.62  on 1997  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 536.62
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

If we use `sjPlot`, we get something similar to your plot:

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(ggplot2)

plot_model(model1, type = "pred", show.p = TRUE, terms = "Sex",
           ci.lvl = 0.95, show.data = FALSE,
           axis.title = c("", "Probability of Error"), title = "") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Female", "Male"))
```

[image]

This shows the estimated probabilities of `Sex` when `ProbErreur` is 0.

The ggplot, on the other hand, shows the overall probability in the `M` and `F` groups:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Sex, Erreur)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.2) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 21, fill = "red", size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.15))
```

[image]

If you want to replicate `sjPlot` in vanilla ggplot, you would need to get model predictions and confidence intervals where `ProbErreur` is 0:

```r
pred_df <- data.frame(Sex = c("F", "M"), ProbErreur = 0)
preds <- predict(model1, newdata = pred_df, se.fit = TRUE)
pred_df$fit <- plogis(preds$fit)
pred_df$upper <- plogis(preds$fit + preds$se.fit * 1.96)
pred_df$lower <- plogis(preds$fit - preds$se.fit * 1.96)

ggplot(pred_df, aes(Sex, fit)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "red", size = 2) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(), limits = c(0, 1)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.05))
```

[image]

You can specify the value of the covariates in your predictions inside of `sjPlot`, and it is also possible to modify the geom layers in `sjPlot` without resorting to calculating your own marginal predictions and plotting directly in ggplot.

<sup>Created on 2023-08-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>